# ngSwitch inside a table

Tags: angular, ng-switch

In my app, I am taking data from a SQL database and displaying it inside a table. I have three components: grid.component.ts, row-display.component.ts, and row-edit.component.ts. I am trying to set row-display.component.ts as the default view (when no rows are selected) and use ngSwitch to switch to row-edit.component.ts, but only on one row, whenever that specific row is "selected" or clicked on.

I'm thinking that I would make some sort of function to see if a specific row was selected, if there was no row selected it would go to row-display and if there was a row, it'd find out which row, pass that row to row-edit and display the template that I have for row-edit but only for that row. For the most part, I'm not sure if how I have things set up is correct and I'm also not sure how to figure out which row was selected because I'm mass displaying things from a database.

Here's where I'm implementing the ngSwitch statement:

```html
    <tr *ngFor="let pto of ptoData">
      <ng-container *ngIf="pto.type === selectedType">
        <ng-container *ngIf="pto.EmpKey === empInfo[selectedEmployee].EmpKey">
          <ng-container [ngSwitch]="isRowSelected()">
            <ng-container *ngSwitchCase="false">
              <pto-row-display></pto-row-display>
            </ng-container>
            <ng-container *ngSwitchCase="true">
              <pto-row-edit></pto-row-edit>
            </ng-container>
          </ng-container>
        </ng-container>
      </ng-container>
    </tr>
```

does that look correct? and then if i figure out how to see which row is selected put that in the function?

Comment: what have you done?

Comment: @Kossel edit made in original post

Comment: @Kossel made another edit to make everything more clear